# ScrollView within FrameLayout within ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-scrollview, android-constraintlayout

I am developing a multipane application, which led me to use `ConstraintLayout` to design the main layout, as it seemed like a great use for it. There are two `FrameLayouts` (left & right panels) as fragment containers, couple of toolbars on top, and a `BottomNavigationView` at the bottom of the left panel.

My problem is with having fragment layouts with `ScrollView` on the right panel. No matter what I tried, I could not get the layout to scroll if it exceeded the visible height. I found a hacky way to fix this issue, by encapsulating the fragment container (`FrameLayout`) with a `ScrollView`, and explicitly setting the fragment root layout height based on the measured height of the `RecyclerView` in a fragment. However, for large lists, this caused a crash (`Layer exceeds max. dimensions supported by the GPU`); and it is not an ideal solution anyways. So now, I want to change the layout.

I know it is not recommended to have a `RecyclerView` within a `ScrollView`; however, I have other elements in the fragment layout, so I need to have that structure. Am I missing something with this `ConstraintLayout` stuff? I am thinking of switching to `RelativeLayout`, as I believe it will fix this issue, but I wanted to ask the community first before doing anything major, as it will take some time to convert the layout.

Here are some details that could potentially help (please let me know if you need more details):

*MainActivity layout:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:id="@+id/main_activity_layout"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical">

   <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
      android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="50dp"
      android:theme="@style/CustomToolbar"
      android:background="@drawable/toolbar_background"
      app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
      app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/main_container"
      app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline_cart_right"
      app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">

      ......toolbar stuff here......

   </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

   <FrameLayout
      android:id="@+id/main_container"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:theme="@style/MainFragStyle"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline_cart_right"
      app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/main_toolbar"/>

      ...... other elements .....

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

*Example Fragment layout:*
(Note: tried playing around with layout height attributes, did not work)

```
<ScrollView
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:fillViewport="true">
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                          android:id="@+id/root_fragment_item"                                                 
                          android:layout_width="match_parent"                                                 
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:focusable="true"
                          android:focusableInTouchMode="true"                                                 
                          android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants">

   <View
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:id="@+id/header_section_background"
      android:background="@color/colorItemHeaderBackground"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline_header_bottom"
      app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

   <View
      android:id="@+id/header_section_triangle"
      android:layout_width="40dp"
      android:layout_height="22dp"
      android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
      android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
      android:background="@drawable/triangle"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline_header_bottom"
      app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.15"
      app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

   <TextView
      android:id="@+id/header_item_title"
      style="@style/ItemHeaderTitle"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline_header_bottom"
      app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.2"/>

   <TextView
      android:id="@+id/header_item_duration"
      style="@style/ItemHeaderSubtitle"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
      android:text=""
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline_header_bottom"
      app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.65"/>

   <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/header_item_image"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:background="@drawable/custom_image_background"
      android:layout_margin="8dp"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline_header_bottom"
      app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/guideline_header_image_start"
      app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
      app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"/>

   <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
      android:id="@+id/item_details"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
      android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
      android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline_header_bottom"/>

   <android.support.constraint.Guideline
      android:id="@+id/guideline_header_bottom"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="172dp"/>

   <android.support.constraint.Guideline
      android:id="@+id/guideline_header_image_start"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.75"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Have you tried using `NestedScrollView` instead of `ScrollView`?

Comment: @Cheticamp yes, it did not work. I should have mentioned that I override the `canScrollVertically` method of `LinearLayoutManager` to `return false` because I don't want the `RecyclerView` to scroll on its own. I am using `RecyclerView` for its support for different view types

Comment: @epekel TBH this seems too hard and complicated to get right, while using the `ConstraintLayout`. Why not use a `LinearLayout` as the root view for the `Fragment`

Comment: @AjilO. that's what I figured, thanks!